# How do I integrate a function that returns a value in terms of another symbol

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sympy, numerical-integration

I am currently trying to integrate a function using `scipy.integrate.quad`, but my function has two variables, the first is `x`, which is a variable being integrated out, and the second is `G`, which I am trying to solve for after the integration is complete.

I've already tried to use `sympy.integrate` which supports the integration of symbols, but my integral is too complex to be evaluated.

An example of the integral I am trying to solve is shown here:

```py
C = integrate.quad(lambda x: x/(1+(3*G)*x)
```

I want to be able to evaluate the integral so that I could then solve for `G` because `C` is a constant value.

I expect the output to be some function of `G` that I can then use to solve for `G`, but I can't figure out how to integrate the function without previously defining `G`.

Answer (score 0):

First note what your ultimate goal is: solve the equation `f(G)==C`, where `f()` is a function of a single argument. Now, it so happens that your `f` is the result of the integration with respect to a second variable. Therefore, simply define a single-argument function that computes this integral as follows:

```
def f(G):
    return quad(lambda x: x/(1+(3*G)*x), 0, 10)[0]
```

and call `scipy.optimize.root_scalar` to solve the equation (with `C==1` in this example)

```
root_scalar(lambda G: f(G)-1, x0=2, bracket = [0,5])
```

> ```
>       converged: True
>            flag: 'converged'
>  function_calls: 10
>      iterations: 9
>            root: 3.1734489114921782
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. If I can ask another question, why did you choose those values for the starting point and bracket? Thanks.

Comment: I am also receiving an error now: "The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be underestimated."

Comment: @Lam All parameters in the code (including integration limits) were selected more or less arbitrarily. I did a plot of `f(G)-1` to get an idea of where the root is (in the domain `G>0`)

Comment: @Lam yeah, I got this warning as well for some parameters. Apparently, the function is not "behaving" well for some parameters/values of `G`. This is something you will have to work on your own (e.g., choose your function and/or parameteres/domain, etc, so that this issues do not occur or do not introduce problems finding the solution). But this has nothing to do with the overall approach described in the answer.